# Insert into Table using case condition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table where i have to check if column 'Type' contains data value as 'V',then i have to insert it as 'F' and or else no change

I am using the below and getting an error as incorrect Syntax near case.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
           ([A] ,[B],
           [C],[D] , CASE [Type] WHEN 'F'THEN 'V' else [Type] as Service type,[E]) select   ([A] ,[B],
           [C],[D] ,[Type],[E]   from   [dbo].[Table2]
```

Comment: Effectively here you've mixed the syntax of using a `SELECT` with an `INSERT` statement, and using `VALUES`.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert statement goes to wrong correct as follow with `case` expression

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([A], [B], [C], [D], [Type], [E]) 
SELECT [A], [B], [C], [D],
       CASE [Type] WHEN 'V'THEN 'F' else [Type] end [Type],[E]
FROM [dbo].[Table2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert [dbo].[Table] (a, type)
    select a, CASE [Type] WHEN 'F'THEN 'V' else [Type]
    from dbo].[Table2]
```